# Scala/Spark idiomatic way to handle nulls in the DataSet?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code read data from a database table and return `DataSet[Cols]`.

```
case class Cols (F1: String, F2: BigDecimal, F3: Int, F4: Date, ...)

def readTable() : DataSet[Cols] = {
    import sqlContext.sparkSession.implicits._

    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"..."
    )).load()
      .select("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4")
      .as[Cols]
  }
```

The values may be nulls. Later it raised runtime exception when using these fields.

```
val r = readTable.filter(x => (if (x.F3 > ...
```

What's the Scala idiomatic way to handle nulls in the DataSet?

I got the error when running the code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.math.BigDecimal.$minus(BigDecimal.scala:563)
        at MappingPoint$$anonfun$compare$1.apply(Mapping.scala:51)
```

Answer (score 4):

[Options](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) are the idiomatic way

```
case class Cols (F1: Option[String], F2: Option[BigDecimal], F3: Option[Int], F4: Option[Date], ...)
```

There is a performance hit as discussed in the [databricks style guide](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#perf-option)

Comment: yeah I hadn't seen the case class .. I like your solution better than mine :)

Comment: Will `.as[Cols]` automatically convert nulls to None? And how should the `filter` be written?

Answer (score 2):

`Option(null)` will return `None`.

Thus, for instance:

```
val r = readTable.filter(x => (if (Option(x.F3).getOrElse(0) >
```

Comment: I actually need the expression to return false if the value is null. How to write it? I tried `if (x.F3 != null && x.F3 > x) ...` but it still raise the java.lang.NullPointerException?

Comment: if (!Option(x.F3).isDefined)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I need to compare with two columns so converting null to zero will not work. I will try your previous solution of isDefined.

Comment: if (x.F3> x).getOrElse(false))

Comment: I've posted a new question on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175306/cannot-prevent-nullpointerexception-happening