# How to check null on scala.math.BigDecimal?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code raises the NullPointerException. Even there is `Option(x._1.F2).isDefined && Option(x._2.F2).isDefined` to prevent the null values?

```
case class Cols (F1: String, F2: BigDecimal, F3: Int, F4: Date, ...)

def readTable() : DataSet[Cols] = {
    import sqlContext.sparkSession.implicits._

    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"..."
    )).load()
      .select("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4")
      .as[Cols]
  }

import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => func}
val j = readTable().joinWith(readTable(), func.lit(true))
readTable().filter(x => 
  (if (Option(x._1.F2).isDefined && Option(x._2.F2).isDefined 
       && (x._1.F2- x._2.F2< 1)) 1 else 0)  //line 51
  + ..... > 100)
```

I tried `!(x._1.F2== null || x._2.F2== null)` and it still gets the exception.

The exception is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.math.BigDecimal.$minus(BigDecimal.scala:563)
        at MappingPoint$$anonfun$compare$1.apply(MappingPoint.scala:51)
        at MappingPoint$$anonfun$compare$1.apply(MappingPoint.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Update:**
I tried the following expression and the execution still hit the line `x._1.F2- x._2.F2`. Is it a way to check if BigDecimal is null?

```
(if (!(Option(x._1.F2).isDefined && Option(x._2.F2).isDefined
       && x._1.F2!= null && x._2.F2!= null)) 0
       else (if (x._1.F2- x._2.F2< 1) 1 else 0))
```

## Update 2

***The exception is gone after I wrapped the minus into `(math.abs((l.F2 - r.F2).toDouble)`.***
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this this to your `if` statement:

`&& (x._1.F2 && x._2.F2) != null`

I've had a similar issue in Java and that's what has worked for me.

Comment: It got the compiler error of `value && is not a member of Option[BigDecimal]`. Can `&&` be applied to `Option(...)`?

Comment: Tried `(x._1.F2== null || x._2.F2== null)` and it still gets the exception.

Comment: try `(x._1.F2 && x._2.F2) != null`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for BigDecimal, on line 563:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/math/BigDecimal.scala#L563

It may be possible that `x._1.F2.bigDecimal` or `x._2.F2.bigDecimal` is `null`, though I'm not really sure how that would happen, given the constructor checks for that. But maybe check for `null` there and see if that solves the problem?

BTW, you should really avoid all the `._1`, `._2`s... You should be able to do something like:

```
val (l: Cols, r: Cols) = x
```

To extract the tuple values.

Comment: The strange thing is I've checked if they are nulls and the line shouldn't be hit if there is any null.

Comment: Guess what, the exception is gone after I wrapped the minus into `(math.abs((l.F2 - r.F2).toDouble)`.